# Using default generic values in C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, dapper

I have some code written in C#. I am trying to write some generic code that I can reuse. My actual code is more complicated. However, the code is question looks like the following:

```
public async Task<T> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sql)
{
  var results = default(T);
  using (var database = new SqlConnection("[ConnectionString]"))
  {
    database.Open();
    results = await database.QueryAsync<T>(sql);                        
  }
  return results;
}
```

When I build my project, I get a compile-time error that says:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>' to 'T'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

I do not fully understand why I'm getting this error. I intend to call it in a manner like this:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
var results = await adapter.ExecuteQueryAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>("SELECT * FROM Customer");
```

In the above, wouldn't `T` be an `IEnumerable<T>`? If that's the case, I do not understand why I'm getting this type conversion error at compile-time.

Thank you!

Comment: `results` has type T and `database.QueryAsync<T>(sql)` returns `IEnumerable<T>`. Just change result type to `IEnumerable<T>` I think that is what you really want. Default value has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I know this is simplified code, but just to be sure... you **really** need to add a mechanism to this code to accept sql parameter data separately from the sql command string. Otherwise you're practically forcing yourself to write horribly insecure code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this.

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sql)
{
  IEnumerable<T> results = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  using (var database = new SqlConnection("[ConnectionString]"))
  {
    database.Open();
    results = await database.QueryAsync<T>(sql);                        
  }
  return results;
}
```

Comment: methinks easy `return await database.QueryAsync<T>(sql);` without any variables

Comment: true that would be equivalent.

Comment: If a local variable is used (despite of @Grundy's comment), why not use the default value, so either `var results = default(IEnumerable<T>);` or equivalently `var results = (IEnumerable<T>)null;` or if you are OK with not using `var`, then `IEnumerable<T> results = null;`. The default value for an interface type is a null reference.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen because in case empty collection - not need checking on null

Comment: @Grundy It's actually provably impossible for that value to be returned, so using `null` simply avoids getting an empty sequence.

Comment: @Servy and using empty sequence simply avoid getting null :-)

Comment: @Grundy But it doesn't.  You could never actually return `null` even if you used `null`.  Again, it's a value that you can prove is never returned; what it is is irrelevant.  Heck, you could just *leave it uninitialized* and *not assign anything to it* if you wanted.

Comment: Yes, @Servy is right. It is much better to leave it uninitialized before the `using` statement. So simply `IEnumerable<T> results;` with no assignment at the declaration. There is no point in setting it to anything (either null or some empty object) that will not be used. The compiler is happy with this approach.

Answer (score 3):

In your `ExecuteQueryAsync` you not need it `results` variable, since you always rewrite it. So your function can be like this

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sql)
{
    using (var database = new SqlConnection("[ConnectionString]"))
    {
        database.Open();
        return await database.QueryAsync<T>(sql);                        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are already good answers here, but I wanted to make sure we had one that supports safe query parameterization. The original code forces you to write incredibly insecure code that **will** result in your app getting hacked. This allows you to avoid that:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<T>> ExecuteQueryAsync<T>(string sql, dynamic Parameters = null)
{
  IEnumerable<T> results;
  using (var database = new SqlConnection("[ConnectionString]"))
  {
    database.Open();
    results = await database.QueryAsync<T>(sql, Parameters);                        
  }
  return results;
}
```

Then you might call it like this:

```
Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
var results = await adapter.ExecuteQueryAsync<IEnumerable<Customer>>(
        "SELECT * FROM Customer WHERE Sales >= @Sales", 
        new {Sales = 500.0m});
```

Comment: methinks it same as @Daniel answer, or i something missed?

Comment: @Grundy It adds support for parameterized queries.

Comment: @Grundy There's a sample for how to call it now.

Comment: if `Parameters` declare as `object` instead of `dynamic` it would work?

Comment: Not sure... that's how I had it first, but I haven't used dapper before so I went to github to check the source. Once I looked, I saw Dapper uses dynamic internally, meaning there's no good reason to object instead. It's gonna end up dynamic anyway.

Comment: Thank you for removing the meaningless initialization `= Enumerable.Empty<T>()` that you had copy-pasted from another answer at first (see comments at Daniel A. White's answer).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Why even leave it uninitialized when you can trivially *remove any need for it in the first place*.  Doing so improves the readability of the code pretty dramatically.

Comment: @Servy Because of the "my actual code is more complicated" statement in the question. There may be something else going on where he needs that variable in the method.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I'd be pretty surprised if any of that absolutely needed to be outside of the `using`.  I would imagine most of it belongs inside the `using`.  If it doesn't, and it's processing the results, it probably belongs in another method, and at a minimum, it can stay inside the `using` even if it doesn't absolutely require the connection.